# Where am I going wrong with this code?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to calculate the sum of the squares of the first n numbers. Here is the code:

```
fun sumSq 0 = 0 |
    sumSq x = x + sumSq(x * x-1);
```

I am getting an uncaught exception Overflow[overflow] error.

Comment: `x*x + sumsq(x-1)`, perhaps? This looks like it should stack-overflow in any language with infinite-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah that did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sumSq( x * x-1) is exactly the same than sumSq( (x * x) - 1) and not like sumSq( x * (x - 1)).

Consequences :

```
   if x = 0 or 1 it's ok.
   if x is greater than 1 (5 for example) 

   sumSq 5 = 5 + sumSq( 5 * 5-1 ) = 5 + sumSq(24) x will never decrease!!!
```

you have got an infinite loop